# If props is missing Should I use memo?

Tags: reactjs

I have such a component

```
import React, { Fragment, memo } from "react";

const Gurdingo = () => {
  return <Fragment>100</Fragment>;
};

export default memo(Gurdingo);
```

Do I need to use memo here?
or react itself understands that it is not necessary to rebuild the component Gurdingo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid the component from re-rendering when it's parent does, you would need to use `React.memo`. React isn't going to automatically stop rendering the component just because it doesn't have any props. We can check this with a [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rubin-npi0z):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [, setToggle] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setToggle(x => !x)}>
        Re-render Parent
      </button>
      <br />
      <Gurdingo />
      <br />
      <GurdingoMemo />
    </div>
  );
}

const Gurdingo = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rendering");
  });
  return <>100</>;
};

const GurdingoMemo = React.memo(() => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rendering Memoized Gurdingo");
  });
  return <>100</>;
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

On first render, both `Rendering` and `Rendering Memoized Gurdingo` are logged to the console. When pressing the button which triggers `App` to re-render, `Rendering` is logged, indicating the component is not skipped.

Comment: How could one decide on whether or not a 'PROPLESS' component should be memoized ? - In other words, why would I want to prevent a propless component from re-rendering [let's say it only has a static image and bunch of h1,p tags] ?

Comment: The general motivation for using `React.memo` to prevent rerenders is to save React from having to do extra work generating the rendered output of a component tree and then diffing it against the existing version to decide if any changes need to be flushed to the DOM. With React.memo, you are declaring that if the props are the same, the rendered output will be the same, so there's no reason to generate it. It's usually something that's done with heavier components (lots of elements) because otherwise React is fast enough and the optimization isn't noticeable.